# Unable to access my minikube cluster from the browser (❗ Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to access a simple minikube cluster from the browser, but I keep getting the following:
`❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.`

I've created an external service for the cluster with the port number of 30384, and I'm running minikube in a docker container.

I'm follwing "Hello Minikube" example to create my deployment.

Step1: I created the deployment:

`kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4`

Step2: I created the external service:
`kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080`

Step3: I ran the service, and that;s where I stuffed up
"`minikube service hello-node`

The full return message:

`❗  Executing "docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}" took an unusually long time: 2.3796077s`
  `Restarting the docker service may improve performance.`
  `Starting tunnel for service hello-node.`
  `Opening service default/hello-node in default browser...`
`❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.`

I tried to run the service to make it accessible from the browser, however, I wasn't able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue resolved it by changing minikube base driver to hyperv from docker.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Your pc will restart after that you can say

```
minikube config set driver hyperv
```

Then `minikube start` will start you with that driver.

This worked for me.

Comment: It wouldn't be his case since he is working with a docker image, how can you get a containerized image in hyper-v?

Comment: He can still work with docker image since kubectl is always available no matter the driver. Driver is there only to allow virtualization with the host OS. I also worked with docker image and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to append `--url` to the `minikube service` command to get it to output anything.

Answer (score 15):

You can get this working by using kubectl's port forwarding capability.
For example, if you are running `hello-node` service:

`kubectl port-forward svc/hello-node 27017:27017`

This would expose the service on `localhost:27017`

You can also mention your pod instead of the service with the same command, you just need to specify your `pods/pod-name`, you can verify your pod name by `kubectl get pods`

Comment: +1 because this works, but the question is, but the question is what's the issue with Minikube and NodePort.

Comment: @Aladin: how to use port-forward with external IP? I get external ip by running the command ```minikube ip```. I run ```curl localhost:27017``` success but ```curl ${minikube ip}:27017``` is timeout

Comment: @Hoang, an external ip is reachable by any hosts, so you don't have to put any port or port-forward.

Comment: @Aladin ohh, but I don't know why I can't access it by external IP. I create a post at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77754060/4768616 . Can you read it and help me to resolve?

Answer (score 3):

try to use:

minikube service --all

it shows and opens the service in browser instance without issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the alternative in the minikube tutorial, this one works for me on windos:

```
kubectl port-forward service/hello-minikube 7080:8080
```

http://localhost:7080/
response:

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=127.0.0.1
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://localhost:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br
accept-language=es-US,es-419;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
connection=keep-alive
host=localhost:7080
sec-ch-ua=" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0
sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows"
sec-fetch-dest=document
sec-fetch-mode=navigate
sec-fetch-site=cross-site
sec-fetch-user=?1
upgrade-insecure-requests=1
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
BODY:
-no body in request-
```