# Minikube M1 - minikube service not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, minikube

I try to follow the instructions on the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#deploy-a-hello-world-app) to deploy a hello world app in the Minikube. So far I created the deployment and exposed the deployment.

Deployment:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default         deployment.apps/web                        1/1     1            1           10m
```

Service:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE                   11m
default         service/web                                  NodePort    10.107.89.59    <none>        8080:30841/TCP               10m
```

When I run below "minikube service web --url" I only got:

```
minikube service web --url

  Starting tunnel for service web.
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

If I run it without the "--url" option, my browser says that the server is not responding.

Did anyone have any similar problems? Why is not the hello world app loading in the browser as in the guide?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to port forward your service since you are accessing to it from outside the cluster,  Find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714919/unable-to-access-my-minikube-cluster-from-the-browser-because-you-are-using-a/71749256#71749256)

Answer (score 1):

The tunnel is created between your Mac and Cluster IP instead of Node IP.

Here is a workaround for your case

1. Get the service cluster **IP**

> `kubectl get svc -o wide`

2. Get the tunnel **PORT** on your Mac

> `ps -ef | grep ssh`

3. Access it from localhost

> `curl http://127.0.0.1:PORT`

if you are using ingress, please refer to [#12089](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/12089)

Remember The bridge network in mac is different from in Linux   [#7332 (comment)](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332#issuecomment-608133325)