# External Ip can't access to kubernetes when deploy in docker desktop macos

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop, kubernetes-service

I am running Kubernetes locally by minikube on docker desktop macOS. I want to access the service Kubernetes by external IP. My problem also has a few similar topic on Stackoverflow but it's from 1, or 2 years before, I do according answer in that topic but was not successful so I create a new topic with full information about my case current.

kubectl version:

```
Client Version: v1.29.0
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.3
```

minikube version

```
minikube version: v1.32.0
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.10
 Git commit:        afdd53b
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 09:04:20 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.10
  Git commit:       311b9ff
  Built:            Thu Oct 26 09:08:15 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.25
  GitCommit:        d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.10
  GitCommit:        v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

file manifest of service, use service type **NodePort**, Pod and Service are still running

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: web-service
  namespace: default
  uid: c5e8ffa5-ac4a-4db0-a692-a1e92c048280
  resourceVersion: '12791'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-01-02T18:51:05Z'
  labels:
    app: nginx
  managedFields:
    # ignore data 
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31856
  selector:
    app: nginx
  clusterIP: 10.111.115.68
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.111.115.68
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

In terminal I run `minikube ip` to get external ip is 192.168.49.2, then run `curl 192.168.49.2:31856`, it is timeout don't return response

[image]

I try to stand in minikube node `minikube ssh` and try again `curl 192.168.49.2:31856` it returns a response success.
I think maybe there was a mistake about the docker desktop's network but can't find to fix

I continue to use port-forward by command `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/web-service 80:80` to forward by port service 80

run `curl localhost:80`, it has the response success same when ssh into minikube
[image]

I try `curl 192.168.49.2:80`
[image]

I think have a config to can connect ip of minikube node from outside but I still not to find right. Please help me if you have any ideal to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using minikube then i would recommend to use the minikube tunnel command to access your services.

```
minikube service <service-name> --url
```

you can read more from [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-nodeport)

Comment: I also got a command before to get IP with port ```192.168.49.2:31856``` but also didn't connect

Comment: did you try or not the command?

Comment: I tried it but didn't run

Comment: if you run the command do you get this output? you need to use http://127.0.0.1:TUNNEL_PORT
$ minikube service hello-minikube1 --url
 http://127.0.0.1:57123
 ❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.

Comment: it print out http://192.168.49.2:31856 and http://127.0.0.1:52312, but i only can curl 127.0.0.1:52312